# Visual Studio 2013 shows empty project properties when VS2008 is used as toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008, project

Visual Studio doesn't display the project properties for a C++ project when a configuration is selected which uses vs90 as its toolset.

When I right-click a project in the affected solution and select "Properties" from the context menu, the property dialog appears empty:

[image: Empty project property dialog]

I remember that it used to show normal compiler options even for older toolsets. What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: You could take a look into the .vcxproj file of this project. Check if there is content in the file and if all XML-tags have a closing-tag.

Comment: The project file seems to be correct, VS also seems to load it correctly because the Solution Explorer shows the files that are part of this project. Building different project configurations also works.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This started happening to me after I tried to edit properties for "All Platforms"

Comment: @Assimilater Not really, the error seemed to be global to all projects. Both VS 2012 and 2013 just didn't get along with the 9.0 toolset all of the sudden (they did before). After this point, even newly created projects had the same error once I added the 9.0 toolset. It never worked after I posted this question (I think I even tried reinstalling them, but I'm not sure). I have since moved on to compile with the 2013 toolset though.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it by making sure that VCTargetsPath (and corresponding VCTargetsPath12 for VS 2013 property) in MSBuild contains a trailing backslash.

Found this by monitoring the devenv.exe process using Process Monitor from sysinternals and noticed that it was trailing to load an invalid path due to missing . After adding it, the project properties started displaying correctly.

Comment: Alas, the values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0` are correct on my machine.

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing, your solution with adding a trailing backslash worked perfectly for me too. I had been trying to find a solution for this rather strange issue for quite some time without success.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem - if I selected one specific build configuration in visual studio the Project Properties dialog went permanently blank and there was no way to go back to a working configuration.

The solution I eventually found was a devenv commandline option: devenv /resetuserdata

Answer (score 0):

I had a specific configuration for a specific platform that was producing a blank properties page in Visual Studio 2010 and 2013.  After trying the solutions here with no luck, I eventually discovered that the root cause was an incorrect `<Platform>` value in the `.vcxproj` file.  In the below screenshot, you can see the before (left) and after (right).

[image: fixes blank properties page]