# Empty Property Dialog with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I migrate my system from Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010) to Visual Studio 2013 (VS2013) by installing VS2013 side by side to VS2010.
Then I opened a VS2010 project where I didn't convert it to VS2013 file format.
When I open the property dialog it is empty. And deleting the .suo files didn't fix the problem (See [Visual Studio 2013 shows empty project properties when VS2008 is used as toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303735/visual-studio-2013-shows-empty-project-properties-for-one-solution)).

I'm glad for hints,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. The problem was VS 2010 German. I uninstalled VS 2010 and VS2013. And then I installed VS 2010 English with SP 1 and VS2013 with SP 4.

And now and forever the property dialog is no more empty :)

Greetings,

Thomas L.